# How to setup to run a query against 2 databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to find out which staff records are in the Production system and not in development with this query: If the id_number is not in the dev system then we need to update. They both have different ip addresses.

```
select     psv.first_name, psv.last_name, psv.login_name, psv.id_number
from       [evolv_cs].dbo.staff_view psv
where      psv.id_number not in (select psv.id_number
                                 from   [evolv_cs_dev].dbo.staff_view dsv)
```

Which gives this error: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'evolv_cs.dbo.staff_view'.

I am not seeing how to run the query with both databases. When I look at object explorer only one of the databases appear so we get the error message. When I click on one database in Object explorer, then that is the one that is available.

I am sorry if this is so basic but - How do I run this so that both databases are present to the query?

I am trying to get both databases to be present for the query. So far only 1 is. Therefore, this query fails.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: --SQL Server 14

Comment: Did you create a linked server? Check out this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: You have to register the other server on the server you are connecting to -- that server will perform the connection.  So if you connect to evolv_cs you need to register evolv_cs_dev on that server in management studio

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, it seems you are connected to your Dev server where you should be seeing `evolv_cs_dev` in your object explorer under databases.

To access tables from `[evolv_cs]` which is on a different server, you need to create a [linked server](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/).

To make it more clear:

1. Tables from a different database in same server can be accessed by `databaseName.schema.tablename` notation. Which your trying to do in your query but since your prod db is on different server its not working.
2. Tables in a database on a different server will have to use `LinkedServerName.DatabaseName.Schema.TableName` notation, which you need to do in your case.

[image]